# The number maximal subgroups of a 2-generated group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a 2-generated group. Then prove that  the number subgroups of index 2 is at most 3.

By Hint i think we have at most 3 cases:

Let $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ and $C_{2}=\langle x\rangle$. Then

1. $a\mapsto x$ and $b\mapsto x$
2. $a\mapsto x$ and $b\mapsto e$
3. $a\mapsto e$ and $b\mapsto x$

Is it true?

Now we use of the first theorem of isomorphism

Comment: Exactly! Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** How many ways can your group map onto the cyclic group of order two?

In response to your edit, yes this is true. So what theorem do you need to apply to get the result?

Comment: Ok. your hint is nice. I think on it

Comment: Also, you should try and include some more detail in your question - tell us what you have tried! In its current for it may get closed.